# DateTimePicker never updates!

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have some `DateTimePicker`s in a form that never update.
I've tried `Value` and `Text`, `Invalidate()` and then `Update()` and also `Refresh()`...

Nothing seems to change their values from the current date!
No matter what I set, the current dates are (relatively)today's!

Is this a .NET 3.5 bug or what?
(No, I cannot use .NET 4 on this project.)

---

If you really want some code, then here it is: `dateTimePicker1.Value = user.BirthDay;`. Also, if I write `MessageBox.Show(user.BirthDay.ToString());` I get a nice box telling the user's birthday (my birthday, on my machine). (So there is a value in the variable...)

---

Should I also mention that they are only for dates and not times?

---

Ok, I see I need to write more:

First of all, the method in which the control is updated is subscribed to the `Form.Load` event. Consequently, it is called/fired/invoked when the form and the controls are visible and "running".

Secondly, look at this pieces of code and their result:

```
MessageBox.Show(user.BirthDay.ToString()); // Shows 12.12.1995 (in my regional format)
dateTimePicker1.Value = user.BirthDay; // assigned to 12.12.1995
MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()); // Shows today's date!
```

That's not nice... The output is today's date. (By today I mean the day in which the code was ran.)

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1); // January 1st, 1900
MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.MinDate.ToString()); // January 1st, 1753 ...
```

Bad control! 1900 doesn't equal to 1753!

```
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;
// In reality, I need it to today's date
MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.MinDate.ToString()); // December 31st, 9998
```

Time warp? O_O

Anyway, the whole code looks like this:

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.user = User.Load(path);
    // this.user is a field.
    // path is a static field which holds the absolute path of the file in which is serialized that data of the user.

    MessageBox.Show(user.BirthDay.ToString()); // Shows 12.12.1995 (in my regional format)
    dateTimePicker1.Value = user.BirthDay; // assigned to 12.12.1995
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()); // Shows today's date!

    dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1); // January 1st, 1900
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.MinDate.ToString()); // January 1st, 1753 ...

    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.MinDate.ToString()); // December 31st, 9998
}
```

So, any solution? xC

Comment: you are first one reporting this bug

Comment: Have you set a `MinDate` for the datetimepicker? Are you sure noone else is overwriting your value? Because I think it is pretty safe to say that there is not a bug in the framework ;-)

Comment: Have you tried setting the Value to `DateTime.Parse(user.BirthDay.ToString())`?

Comment: Would you insert your `BithDay` property code?

Comment: @Saeed - So I've noticed when writing the title... @Klaus - `MinDate` is January 1st, 1900. Does it matter? @Evan - The problem is with the control, not the DateTime class. @Saeed - BirthDay is not a property, it is a field which is serialized. I have already mentioned that the variable is fine. Edit: Shall I mention that the `MaxDate` holds no value?

Comment: You are obviously doing something wrong, because it works. Tryed in Dev10, .Net 3.5, no problem.

Comment: You should insert your code with more detail, for example where do you read serialized data, whats the relation of maxdate or mindate to your code and etc

Comment: @Tomas, the only thing I am doing to the control(s) is setting their value after the `User` class is successfully loaded. @Saeed, the data is (re)serialized when the form is closed and is deserialized and displayed when the form loads. The code I wrote is all the code. BTW, setting `MinDate` or `MaxDate` doesn't work either... Could it be too many operations done at a time? O_O

Comment: (cannot edit anymore...) I am putting for a round of World of Warcraft tonight so I won't be online... I'd damn love it if someone can figure it out...

Comment: It looks like the control is readonly. But a DateTimePicker doesn't have a ReadOnly property. What happens if you just assign `new DateTime(1995,12,12)` to `dateTimePicker1.Value`? If that _does_ work, the problem must be in your user.BirthDay field.

Comment: It does **not** work, else I wouldn't have posted this question, right?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One small hint with this trouble: my problem was that I had the DateTimePicker set to checked=false and (by mistake) ShowCheckbox=false;
With this setup I could set to DTPicker whatever value I wanted, but it won't udate itself.

Comment: This was the problem, it happens because when you right click 'Reset' the DateTimePicker value, it changes 'Checked' to False !

Comment: This did the job for me too, however, I had two TabPage controls with exactly the same kind of nesting for the contained controls etc., and for one of them I never had any problems. On the other TabPage, the (DateTimePicker) control never updated on the UI, but setting Checked to True for that DateTimePicker solved this (again, on the other it worked with both settings).

Comment: One more thing I just noticed - the comment for the Checked property of the DateTimePicker says "When ShowSelectBox is true, determines if the check box is checked, indicating that the user has selected a value.". The thing is - there is no ShowSelectBox property on my DateTimePicker control. Looking at the most recent version on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.checked(v=vs.90).aspx), the description has been updated, so might have to update our help files.

Comment: Same problem in a vb.net project I was just trying to fix. Whodathunkit? Thanks for posting the fix!

Comment: This control even purges the successfully assigned value when setting `DateTimePicker.Checked` to `false` afterwards (by code in the forms Load event)! So, there is no way to assign an initial value that is not enabled (checked) by default.... -.-

Comment: Please check out this answer if you previously used your DateTimePicker as a checked version and changed back to a normal picker. That was my scenario. A co-worker preferred it not be checked, changed ShowCheckbox to false but never set checked=true (which is its default value). Very painful to debug. Thank you for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

The standard diagnostic for a form not updating its visual appearance, but you seeing the property update with the debugger just fine is using the wrong form instance.  Like this for example:

```
var frm = new Form1();  // Wrong!!
frm.UpdateBirthDay(user.BirthDay);
```

Diagnose this by altering your code like this:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = user.BirthDay;
this.Show();   // <=== add this
```

Comment: Interesting answer but I am afraid this is not the case. The control is updated on the `Form.Load` event, which fires when the form and the controls are already visible. Also setting the `MinDate` or `MaxDate` doesn't seem to work!

Comment: The form is *not* yet visible when the Load event fires.  If it is then there's something really wrong.  Set a breakpoint and look at the call stack.  Make sure you don't see the constructor.

Comment: Don't use MessageBox to debug this.  It pumps a message loop, allowing other event handlers is your form to run.  Use Console.WriteLine, look in the Output window.

Comment: You've exhausted our crystal balls.  Post a minimal version of your project, cut down to the essentials but still exhibiting this problem, to a file sharing service or paste bin.  So we can repro this very mysterious problem on our own machines.

Comment: Ok, while putting the form in another project I have noticed that the problem is no more. (But it's still up in the original project!)

Answer (score 0):

My work around to update a stuborn DateTimePicker to display its current value and also update its related DataBindings is to toggle its .Enabled property.

```
myDateTimePicker.Enabled = !myDateTimePicker.Enabled;
myDateTimePicker.Enabled = !myDateTimePicker.Enabled;
```