# How to programatically dismiss the calendar of a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a Windows Form that uses a good amount of DateTimePicker controls.
As per spec, the controllers need to show 'no date' initially till user manually selects a date.

As per the DateTimePicker functionality, we cant assign 'nothing' as a value.
So what we do is set a default minimum date, and then change the custom format of the control to "", to give the illusion of an empty field.

A quirk we have found is that when the user clicks on the DateTimePicker and selects a new date for the first time, his initial click does not dismiss the calendar. So instead the calendar persists, and the user has to manually click outside the control to dismiss the calendar.

To make the user experience slightly worse, while in this state the calendar is immune to any further date selection. So the date selection is stuck with the initially selected date, and the user needs to click out.

Once a date has been selected by the control, selecting a new date dismisses the calendar as expected.

My best guess would be that it would have something to do with the custom format that is there originally, which causes a hiccup with the control when a new properly formatted date is selected.

I am trying to find a way to 'force' the calendar to dismiss if open on value change, but I am not finding the way to do this.
I have even tried to set focus elsewhere on value change, but no luck either.

Has anybody else experienced this behavior and/or know of a way around it?
Thanks!

Some of the code-----------

```
//if dateTime property has not been saved, then call ClearDateTime on the controller, else display the saved value.

public static void ClearDateTime(DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        dtp.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        //set the format
        dtp.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

        // set custom format to empty
        dtp.CustomFormat = " " ;
    }

// When value is changed/date is selected
private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainFormUtilities.ShowDateTime(this.DateTimePicker);
        this.LockFormDown();
    }

public static void ShowDateTime(DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        dtp.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Long;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to replicate this but can't. I managed to set a min date and hide the text like you suggested, but then I put `dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long` in the `dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged` event and it behaved like you'd expect on selecting a date. Can you show your initial and on-select code?

Comment: In this case I would add check box near date time picker(DTP). Checked box would enable DTP and unchecked not set DTP ('nothing' value)

Comment: @Rawling, Ive added some of the code. hopefully it gives the idea of what is happening.

Comment: @Reniuz. that was actually the solution I have resulted to. Seems to solve a couple of user experience problems we have been experience with our slightly hacked DateTimePicker problems, without spending money on a custom built controller.
Thanks you!

Comment: You are welcome. Of course custom control with combobox + DTP will be very handy than 2 controls. ;)

Comment: @Reniuz, yeah I agree with that. Considering where the project currently is at the moment, with a potential rewrite soon, I think this will be suitable for now. Then next time we can implement the date controllers with a bit more foresight. :)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to manually raise the CloseUp event, please refer to the solutions here, [How can I programmatically close the dropdown calendar of a datetimepicker or update the dropdown calendar to reflect the .Value property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014280/how-can-i-programmatically-close-the-dropdown-calendar-of-a-datetimepicker-or-up).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where a client insisted on having the field show no date (appear blank). I gave up on trying to hack the standard .NET DateTimePicker and used the DevExpress DateEdit control which does allow a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have pursued that was most practical for my project was the suggestion by Reniuz, to use a checkbox to control the values and behaviour of the DateTimePicker.
If a user wants to add a date, he selects the checkbox which enables the Picker and defaults to todays date.
If he wants to clear the date (ie not submit a date after all) he unchecks the checkbox which clears the picker with a empty format and we save nothing to the database.

If I had the points I would upvote all the other suggestions. They were helpful, but this solution seemed to be the practical path for us. Thanks to all again!